# NSIS can't use a macro when using Modern UI

Tags: macros, include, nsis, nsis-mui

I have a file `section-db.nsh` containing:

```
!macro uninstall_myrian
    Delete $APPDATA\Intrasense\settings\admin.txt
    Delete $APPDATA\Intrasense\settings\user.txt    
!macroend
```

and `test.nsi` with

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "section-db.nsh"

Name "Software"
OutFile "installer.exe"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

Section hello
SectionEnd
```

Should compile correctly, right? well no:

> ```
> !include: "section-db.nsh"
> !macro: macro named "uninstall_myrian" already found!
> !include: error in script: "section-db.nsh" on line 2
> Error in script "Y:\prog\scripts\installer-script\test.nsi" on line 2 -- aborting creation process
> ```

If I comment the MUI2.nsh include, it compiles correctly.

If I rename the macro to `myrian_uninst`, it compiles correctly.

What's the problem?

Comment: If you are using a NSIS version other than 2.46 you should tell us...

Comment: No, I'm using 2.46. Something must be wrong with the fact that I'm using it with Parallels on the Mac's folder...

Comment: Add a !warning to the start of the .nsh so you can tell if you included it twice by mistake in your real code...

Comment: Well this is real code. I get the same error if I include define the macro in the nsi file, so it's not an inclusion problem

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem while running on real hardware you should file a bug report...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than a missing `!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English` your code compiles without warning in NSIS 2.46